# How to position one element comparing to others in flex-between container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have to containers. One contains 5 (or any other number of elements) and has flex-between, another contains only one element.

Is it possible to position element in second container right under third element of first container with flexbox css? In this situation we don't know distance between elements in first container. [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/angelzzz/crs4kmht/9/)

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 800px; //this amount here for example, in real project it is 100% or auto
}
.element {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: yellow;
  margin: 10px;
}
.element--green {
  background-color: green;
}
.element--red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<p>
first container
</p>
<div class="container">
  <div class="element">
  
  </div>
  <div class="element">
  
  </div>
  <div class="element element--green">
  
  </div>
  <div class="element">
  
  </div>
  <div class="element">
  
  </div>
</div>
<p>
second container
</p>
<div class="container container--small ">
  <div class="element element--green">
  
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use justify-content: center as above for this example, but I assume your general scenario could be that your trying to align to any of the elements in the above container.   As far as pure css is concerned I don't believe this is possible with Flexbox.  The only thing I can think of here at the moment is you have an equal number of containers in each row and hide the containers you do not want to be seen but that seems a bit ugly.

As another thought this seems better suited to css grid.   This is fairly well supported now on the latest version of most browsers, however if you need to support Internet Explorer then your probably out of luck.

If you were able to support grid then something like this would work.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="element">
  </div>

  <div class="element">
  </div>

  <div class="element element--green">
  </div>

  <div class="element">
  </div>

  <div class="element">
  </div>

  <div class="element element--green col3">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  width: 800px; 
}
.element {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: yellow;
  margin: 10px;
}
.element--green {
  background-color: green;
}
.element--red {
  background-color: red;
}
.col3 {
  grid-column: 3;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just add

```
.container--small{
  justify-content:center;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/crs4kmht/11/

Comment: 5 elements was just an example. It can be 6 or 10 or 4